# \n não funciona no IE8 - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá. Estou tendo problemas com o IE8, somente nele, outros navegadores e versões diferentes ja foram testadas e funcionaram, somente no IE8 não funciona.

Tenho uma página de perguntas em SIM/NÃO como escolha em botões radio. Em baixo um botão enviar. Quando o usuário responde e clica em enviar, joga as perguntas com respostas na textarea. Porém, no IE8, não acata o \n na textarea, então fica tudo numa linha só.

Ja usei `\n`, `\r\n`, `\cr` e até o codigo `ASCII 13`, e mesmo assim, no IE8 não funciona. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<script>
function PreencherCampo(){
    var procn1 =  document.getElementById("procn1").innerHTML;
    var pergunta1 =  document.getElementById("pergunta1").innerHTML;
    var pergunta2 =  document.getElementById("pergunta2").innerHTML;
    var pergunta3 =  document.getElementById("pergunta3").innerHTML;
    var procfield = document.getElementById("procfield").innerHTML;
    var pecsug = document.getElementById("pecsug").innerHTML;

    var elementos1 = document.getElementsByName('pergunta1'); 
    var resposta1 = '';
        for (i = 0; i < elementos1.length; i++) {
        if (elementos1[i].checked) {
        resposta1 = elementos1[i].value;
        }
    }

    var elementos2 = document.getElementsByName('pergunta2'); 
    var resposta2 = '';
        for (i = 0; i < elementos2.length; i++) {
        if (elementos2[i].checked) {
        resposta2 = elementos2[i].value;
        }
    }

    var elementos3 = document.getElementsByName('pergunta3'); 
    var resposta3 = '';
        for (i = 0; i < elementos3.length; i++) {
        if (elementos3[i].checked) {
        resposta3 = elementos3[i].value;
        }
    }

        document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = procn1 + '\r\n'+
                        pergunta1 + ': ' + resposta1 + '\r\n'+ 
                        pergunta2 + ': ' + resposta2 + '\r\n'+ 
                        pergunta3 + ': ' + resposta3 + '\r\n\n'+
                        procfield + '\r\n'+
                        pecsug;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Posta a parte HTML, mas até aonde da a entender `\n` é quebra de linha em campos de texto, com input e textarea, ou elemento `<pre>`, mas em html o correto seria `<br>`.

Comment: Veja se essa solução funciona: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263614/new-line-character-n-not-supported-in-ie-8-browser

Answer (score 2):

Como outros já referiram tens de usar `<br />`, isso é o que semanticamente é correto em HTML uma vez que estás a gerar uma string HTML.

Podes também simplificar o teu código e torná-lo independente do numero de perguntas. Uma sugestão seria assim:

```
function PreencherCampo() {
    var procn1 = document.getElementById('procn1').innerHTML;
    var pecsug = document.getElementById('pecsug').innerHTML;
    var procfield = document.getElementById('procfield').innerHTML;

    var respostas = [1, 2, 3].reduce(function(str, nr) {
        var p = document.getElementById('pergunta' + nr).innerHTML;
        var r = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByName('pergunta' + nr), function(el) {
            return el.checked && el.value;
        })[0] || '';
        return [p, ': ', r, '<br/>'].join('');
    });
    document.getElementById('resposta').innerHTML = [procn1, respostas, procfield, pecsug].join('<br/>');
}
```

Não testei, mas se tiver algum bug faz um jsFiddle com o teu HTML que corrijo.